# Perl CSV reading characters that aren't there

Tags: csv, perl, utf-8

I'm reading in a file using Perl's `Text::CSV_XS` package which I am reading on Ubuntu:

```
open my $fh, '<:encoding(utf8)', 'file.csv' or die "Can't read csv: $!"; # error shows on this line
while (my $row = $list->getline ($fh)) {
....
}
```

and this reads just fine until one line gives an error:

```
UTF-8 "\xE9" does not map to Unicode at 0.xlsx_to_json.pl line 198, <$_[...]> line 14019.
```

looking online, this suggests that this is a ê character or something similar, which is strange because I don't see any such characters on line 14109, that line looks just like any other line.

1. I tried changing the open line to

   open my $fh, '<', 'file.csv'

but that gives the same error.

2. I tried opening the CSV and saving as CSV with a different delimiter, but I can't do that in Excel 2016 anymore, the option to change the delimiter simply doesn't appear
3. I tried opening in LibreOffice to save as a CSV, but an update removed the ability to change the delimiter

How can I read this CSV file without this strange error?

Comment: Re "*this suggests that this is a ê character*", No, It's not suggesting that at all. ê encoded using UTF-8 is C3 AA, but it has a problem with a E9 in the file

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your file is not a valid UTF-8 file. Byte E9 appears where it's not expected.

Followed by two continuation bytes = ok

```
$ perl -M5.010 -MEncode=decode -e'
   decode("UTF-8", "\xE9\xBF\xBF", Encode::FB_WARN | Encode::LEAVE_SRC);
   say "done";
'
done
```

Not followed by two continuation bytes = bad

```
$ perl -M5.010 -MEncode=decode -e'
   decode("UTF-8", "\xE9\x41", Encode::FB_WARN | Encode::LEAVE_SRC);
   say "done";
'
UTF-8 "\xE9" does not map to Unicode at -e line 2.
done
```

Fix your bad data.